# Prepending a node in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add a div before another div.

```
<div class = "abc">    
    <div class= "asd"> </div>
    <div class= "asd"> </div>
    <div class= "asd"> </div>
    <div class= "new"> </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to append a 
`<p> add</p>` before `<div class="new"></div>` but when i use $('.new').prepend`('<p> </p>')` the p tag is adding inside the div. How to overcome this issue

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.new').before('<p> add</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "abc">    
    <div class= "asd">1 </div>
    <div class= "asd">2 </div>
    <div class= "asd">3</div>
    <div class= "new">4 </div>
</div>
```

Use [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery `insertBefore()`:

```
$('<p>add</p>').insertBefore('.new');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/opjn2wn7/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) instead.

```
$(".new").before("<p>add</p>");
```